# Conditional table cell in mapped function React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, material-ui

I have an array that is mapped inside a Table and I want to check if the object property "userName" is the same with the header so I know where to place that value, otherwise should be shown "0".

Below is how the table after the mapped is done:

```
{report.data.map(obj => (
                  <React.Fragment>
                    <TableCell>{obj.userName === users[0] ? obj.workedHours : "0"}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{obj.userName === users[1] ? obj.workedHours : "0"}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell>{obj.userName === users[2] ? obj.workedHours : "0"}</TableCell>
                  </React.Fragment>
                ))}
```

In the mapped function, users is just the array with the users like

```
users = ["User 1", "User 2", "User 3"]
```

And `report.data` is an array of objects for every project:

```
[{userName: "User 1", rate: 5, clientName: "client A", workedHours: 8},
 {userName: "User 2", rate: 3, clientName: "client B", workedHours: 5}]
```

And this how the table ends:

[image]

Can you help me to show the value for every user just where it exists and otherwise show "0"?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What does your `report.data` look like?

Comment: Edited the post to show how `report.data` looks like. Thank you for warning

Comment: Did you see the difference in casing?  "User 1" === "user 1" will always be false, because of the uppercase "U".

Comment: I think you only need `obj.userName.toLowerCase() === users[0].toLowerCase()`

Comment: @BjørnNyborg the real data is alright from this point of view, here was written just for example, but thank you, i corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an react example.

I made it even more dynamic, by iterating the users for the header columns too.

How will the data look if a user has been working on multiple clients?

```js
const users = ["User 1", "User 2", "User 3"];

const projects = [
  {
    projectName: "project 1", 
    data: [
      {userName: "User 1", rate: 5, clientName: "client A", workedHours: 8},  
      {userName: "User 2", rate: 3, clientName: "client B", workedHours: 5}
    ]
  }, 
  {
    projectName: "project 2", 
    data: [
      {userName: "User 3", rate: 6, clientName: "client A", workedHours: 5}
    ]
  }
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>Project:</td>
      {users.map(user => (
        <td><span>{user}</span></td>
      ))}
    </tr>

    {projects.map(project => (
      <tr>
        <td><span>{project.projectName}</span></td>

         {users.map(user => {
          
          // Filter for only users that has worked on the project
          const usersOnProject = project.data.filter(obj => obj.userName === user)
          
          // If there is users on the project, iterate them
          if(usersOnProject.length) {
            return (
              <td>
                {usersOnProject.map(obj => obj.userName === user && obj.workedHours)}
              </td>
            )
          }
          
          // Else if no users on the project, return 0
          return (
            <td>0</td>
          )
        })}
      </tr>
    ))}

  </table>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
table td + td, table th + th {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse:
}

span {
  color: red;
}

td, th {
  padding: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: you gave me an idea with mapping the users, but the problem is not with `clientName` which is not used yet, just present in object, but if more users worked on the same project. As you can see in the photo that is attached in the question, instead of showing on the first row next values: "1 8 2.5" it shows "0 0 2.5 | 1 0 0 | 0 8 0" even with `{report.data.map(obj => (
                  users.map(user => (
                
                  <TableCell>{obj.userName === user ? obj.workedHours : "0"}</TableCell>
                
                  )
                )))}`

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data in the case you have multiple users, working on the same project?

Comment: my first array of objects is like this: `[{projectName: "project 1", data: [{userName: "User 1", rate: 5, clientName: "client A", workedHours: 8},
 {userName: "User 2", rate: 3, clientName: "client B", workedHours: 5}]}, {projectName: "project 2", data: [{userName: "User 3", rate: 6, clientName: "client A", workedHours: 5}]}`. From this i am using the projectName as first cell of every row and then mapping the data to show every hour under the corresponding user

Comment: @VladPopa I have updated the answer with the provided data example. 

Comment: You are a total lifesaver, thank you for your time and interest, it worked as expected and I understood how it was supposed to be made :D